# Strict f77 compiler

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am new to fortran programming + compiling. I am trying to compile an old f77 code. I compiled it using gfortran and ran the executable but I got the following error message:

```
Program received signal SIGBUS: Access to an undefined portion of a memory object.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x103e40e62
#1  0x103e4162e
#2  0x7fff8ace0cf9
#3  0x103a50e85
#4  0x103a54374
#5  0x103a4e095
#6  0x103a4b935
#7  0x103a4c19d
Bus error: 10
```

I spoke to the creator of the code and he mentioned that he used a f77 compiler. Does anyone know where I can get a f77 compiler? I am using Mac OS 10.7.5 (Lion). Or is this an error anyone recognizes? I am new to fortran compiling, so I may need detailed help. Thanks!

Comment: I think you can get closer to f77 with `gfortran -std=f95`.

Comment: @wallyk. Thanks for the reply. So I typed in my terminal line:     gfortran -std=f95 -o exexutable_file file.f.                     I got the error:                                                                                                  
Error: GNU Extension: ACCESS specifier in OPEN statement at (1) has value 'APPEND'
file.f:308.72:

            OPEN(48,file='results.bin',access='append') .             Not sure what the error means. Any advice?

Comment: It means your cide is nit Fortran 77 compliant. Do not use that option and do not search a Fortran 77 compiler. Try to use a debugger to findcthe place where the program crashes. And again, you do NOT want a strict f77 compiler.

Comment: try `gfortran -g -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -Wall `

Comment: is this error while compiling or running?

Comment: The options that I use with gfortran to compile FORTRAN 77 for debuggin: `gfortran  -O2 -ffixed-form  -ffixed-line-length-none  -W  -Wall -pedantic  -fimplicit-none  -Wsurprising  -Waliasing  -Wimplicit-interface  -Wunused-parameter  -fcheck=all  -pedantic  -fbacktrace`.  (The formatting breaks up options ... minus sign should be joined with the word.)  With old code, some of these may be too strict, such as implicit-none, pedantic, etc.  Some of these options might reveal the cause your memory problem.

Answer (score 0):

On my Linux system, there is a g77 command which has a symbolic link from f77.

After looking around, it seems to be part of package `compat-gcc-34-g77.i686`<s>, but I haven't yet figured out how that got loaded.</s>

It seems to have been bundled from a standard set of Fedora language options.  Though I am running Fedora 16, it is tagged from Fedora 15.  Perhaps try installing `compat-gcc` or `compat-gcc-34-g77`.